# Can we convert this nested loop, finding_indice to recursive?

Tags: c, arrays, search, recursion, iteration

Can we modify this nested loop to recursive function?
**Target:** Find two indice in an int array whose sum equal to given target value. Here's the working iterative code, *how can I consider this function in a different way as a recursive?*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 15
int find_indice(const int arr[],int size,int target,int *ind_1,int *ind_2);

int main(){
    int arr[SIZE]={0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,15,-5,0,9,10,23};
    int target=-2;
    int ind1,ind2;

    find_indice(arr,SIZE,target,&ind1,&ind2);

    if(ind1!=-1 && ind2!=-1){
        printf("array[%d]=>%d,array[%d]=>%d \n",ind2,arr[ind2],ind1,arr[ind1]);
    }
    else{
        printf("Not found! \n");
        printf("array[%d]=>%d,array[%d]=>%d \n",ind2,0,ind1,0);
    }
    return 0;
}

int find_indice(const int arr[],int size,int target,int *ind_1,int *ind_2){

    int i,j,found=0;

    for(i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<size;j++){
            if((arr[i]+arr[j])==target){
                *ind_1=i;
                *ind_2=j;
                found=1;
            }
        }
    }

    if(found==0){
        *ind_1=-1;
        *ind_2=-1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to transform it to recursive? Usually people go the way around, from the more readable recursive solution to the more performant iterative one.

Comment: It was a midterm exam question, the professor said us each question can be done as a recursive. I wonder how it works recursive in two branch. I can do first/last occurance recursively, but this function seems that it needs two recursive branch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to turn your loops into a recursive call of the same function, but here are a few remarks on your code:

the `printf` statement is meaningless in case you do not find the indices.

Why do you stop at `i<size-1` in the outer loop?  The test should be `i < size`, unless you want indices to be different, but your code does not implement this constraint.

`find_indice()` should return the found status, it would be much simpler than storing bogus indices in `*ind_1` and `*ind_2`, and would allow you to use the proper type for array indices: `size_t`.

You should return from `find_indice()` immediately when you find a match, no need to try all possibilities.

You can halve the running time by starting the inner loop at `j=i` instead of `j=0`.  Note that for a different target, say `-10`, `find_indice()` could return the same index in both `*ind_1` and `*ind_2`.  This may not be what is expected. You would start the inner loop at `j=i+1` if it is not wanted.

Comment: Firstly, you're right inner loop must have started j=i+1, this is my old version. Thanks your attention.

Comment: We can consider very simple method, but i don't know how can i replace it. I have started from size-1 but there are many posibilities to reach match. So inner loop need to start +1. In addition, I think that when match is possible, we need to return them as an output parameter to main function. In case otherwise it's not needed.